# Is this the correct way to install SSRS for web access? & to integrate with PowerBI

Tags: azure, networking, reporting-services, dns, powerbi

I hired a Microsoft Partner to help me set up my locally hosted SSRS on Win10 so that when I go to my domain outside my network it would point to it, and I have a domain I can connect to with the PowerBI app on my android device.

Locally it works fine, but externally I get asked my username/password which does not work. This MS Partner has gotten me to pay for an Azure AD account and a PowerBI license, VPN and potentially getting me to set up a VM on Azure to get it working.

He been at it for hours every day since Sunday (its Wednesday now) trying to get this work. I unfortunately do not know much about the set up side for it to work over the internet - I was able to set it up locally and got frustrated and now paying someone to do it for me but I am not sure if this is going to ever end at this rate. I am actually no closer to the getting it working, but obviously paying more for licensing and labour. This was meant to a personal project - I am no way making a business out of it.

Can someone give some insight on the set up to get a web domain to connects to SSRS. Is the partner going the right path?

Aparently only need to do a setspn -s etc but its refusing the domain\user

Have ensured firewall allows port 80 access, DNS forwarding was working to local reportserver ok, aparently he wants me to sign in with microsoft account but its a gmail account instead of the domain one but MS won't allow set up of a "work" account just gmail.
He has set up AD, VPN and now wants to set up a VM.

Answer (score 0):

One approach for exposing securely is through Active Directory Application Proxy -

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jtarquino/2016/07/04/accessing-sql-server-reporting-services-mobile-reports-with-the-power-bi-app-from-the-internet-using-active-directory-application-proxy/